# Open Closed Principle C#: Is Private Set + Constructor Init an Example of it?

Tags: c#, oop, solid-principles, open-closed-principle

My Workmate believes that the following code is an example of the Open Closed Principle in C#:

```
public class MyClass
{
   public int Id { get; private set; }

   public int Count{ get; private set; }

   public int Maximum{ get; private set; }

   public MyClass(int id, int count, int maximum)
   {
       Id = id;
       Count = count;
       Maximum = maximum;
   }

   public PrintValueWithText()
   {
      Conlose.Writeline($"The value of the Id property is: {Id.ToString()}");
   }
}
```

The reason that he gives is that: "The Id property's value is closed for modification once the class is constructed".

I believe this is an incorrect interpretation.

It is my understanding that the open closed principle has nothing to do with the value of a property being closed for modification.

I believe that the Open Closed principle only relates to designing the class so that extending the **behavior** of the class is possible without modifying the existing code.

i.e. if i was to go in and edit the `PrintIdWithText` method to also print the value of `Count` on a new line I would be violating the principle. Because I'm modifying the existing class.

In order to satisfy the principle, I must design the class so that its extendable so that I can for example, inject in the print functionality by composition.

Which would allow me to a later date, add functionality to print the print the value of `Maximum` on a new line.

Is my interpretation of the principle correct?

Is his interpretation incorrect?

Comment: You are right. Workmate's wrong.

Comment: Constructor parameter + properties with public getter is rather example of  *immutable* object (typically such ones are `struct`). For good example of "O" in solid see e.g. [this tutorial](http://joelabrahamsson.com/a-simple-example-of-the-openclosed-principle/).

Comment: What happens if you need *another* statistic like an average? You'll have to modify this class. What if you want to "print" to another target, like a file or stream? You'll have to modify it. This class is immutable but definitely not closed for modification. In fact, combining the statistics with the code that "prints" them, whatever that may mean, increases the need for modification

Comment: Yes your interpretation is correct, and this example is just as creation of immutable data structure or class and that's it, the OCP says that when you will want to extend the behavior of this class you should not modify this class!

Comment: I don't think either of you are wrong, Your workmate has described the implementation of how you follow the principle whereas you're describing the reason why. Your workmate never said you should modify existing classes (that's what I got from your question at least). If that is his understand then he is wrong, but the fact that he has set private setters on the members is definitely a step in the open close principle.

Comment: @KieranDevlin How is _"The Id property's value is closed for modification once the class is constructed"_ a description _"of how you follow the principle"_? What "workmate" got wrong is the abstraction level. The _code_ shouldn't need to change, not the value of some property. While you are technically correct, he didn't say "it's ok to alter the code, though", his misconception is pretty clear.

Comment: Actually, on second read, it takes me wonder if "workmate" was trying to be "funny"... in some weird kind of sense.

Comment: @KieranDevlin My workmate believed that closing the Id property for modification of its value after construction is fulfilling the the "Closed" part of the open closed principle. He was purely thinking in terms of value modification. I have pointed out the comments in this thread to him and we now both understand that his interpretation of it was incorrect. I asked him: "in your interpretation what fulfills the Open for extension part" and he then realized he needed to read up on the principle more. Thanks

Comment: @fourbeatcoder Then no, hes wrong, there's more to it than just that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct.
The Open-Closed principle has nothing to do with mutability or property values at runtime.

The Open-closed principle is about architecting the code so that we can add new behaviour *without* modifying existing working code.

I have rewritten your code to follow the OCP. In this case, `MyClass` was *open* for extension to print the `Maximum` property by introducing a new `IClassPrinter`, in this case the `FancyClassPrinter`.

Bear in mind that  it is impossible to make a class fully closed, there will always be modifications that we cannot foresee, so the the OCP is a guide not a target.

For you code, this is a bit of a contrived example, and might be overkill for such simple program. Also note that the Single Responsibility Principle required us to move the printing responsibility to another class, even if were not following OCP.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public interface IClassPrinter{
  void PrintValue(MyClass myClass);
}

public class NormalClassPrinter: IClassPrinter{
  public void PrintValue(MyClass myClass)
   {
      Console.WriteLine($"The value of the Id property is: {myClass.Id.ToString()}");
   }
}

public class FancyClassPrinter: IClassPrinter{
  public void PrintValue(MyClass myClass)
   {
      Console.WriteLine($"The value of the Id property is: {myClass.Id.ToString()}");
      Console.WriteLine($"The value of the Maximum property is: {myClass.Maximum.ToString()}");
   }
}

public class MyClass
{
   public int Id { get; private set; }

   public int Count{ get; private set; }

   public int Maximum{ get; private set; }

   public MyClass(int id, int count, int maximum)
   {
       Id = id;
       Count = count;
       Maximum = maximum;
   }

   public void PrintValueWithText(IClassPrinter classPrinter)
   {
      classPrinter.PrintValue(this);
   }
}

class MainClass
{
   static public void Main(string[] args)
   {
    MyClass myClass = new MyClass(0,0,0);

    myClass.PrintValueWithText(new NormalClassPrinter());
    myClass.PrintValueWithText(new FancyClassPrinter());

   }
}
```